# IF statement in java doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I have this code in my android app:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values)
{
    if (values.length > 0)
    {
        String message = new String(values[0]);

        boolean isConfig = message.contains("Messages");

        if (isConfig)
        {
              String configFile = message;
        }
        else
        {
            receiveTxt.setText(message);
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

            if (vibrate)
            {
                v.vibrate(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm stepping through the code, it will pass the first if statement, but it will never step into the second if/else statements. It just steps over all the time... Any ideas why?

Thank you

Comment: `if` works good :) You're probably using it wrong.

Comment: really you need `byte` here, not an String?

Comment: event if the isConfig is false it should enter the else statement which is not happening. And yes, the IF statement is works good, is the title I've given to this question is a bit misleading ... sorry

Comment: check the value of `message`

Comment: message is never null and isConfig is always either true or false ...

Comment: I don't know what environment you are using but AFAIK the debugger in some IDE (in my own experience, Eclipse) sometimes just fails to work with breakpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If is working fine.The boolean value of isConfig is always false thats why  code flow is not stepping into your second if statement.

Check the content of values[0] using a debugger.

Comment: Yes it should...attach a debugger and debug your code step by step.then you will be able to locate the issue

Comment: stepping through will always take me on the closing bracket of the first if statement. If I'll place breakpoints on the lines with String configFile = message; and receiveTxt.setText(message); it never stops in there ...

Comment: got it ..if you are placing breakpoint String configFile = message here and code flow stops here,this means your second if is executed, u just do not know because you are not printing any logs there..print a log like Log.i(LOG,"ConfigFile :"+configFile); and check

Comment: CORRECT!!! Only assigning the value to string wasn't good enough and that's why I didn't see is stepping into. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here `onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values)`, you are making a two dimensional array which contains one array of your bytes. Instead use `byte...`, and treat it like an array.